# Вывод контента главной страницы на WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Какую функцию нужно написать в index.php чтобы контент из консоли выводилось. 
В интернете много искал не нашёл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для вывода контента любой записи внутри главного цикла WordPress надо использовать `the_content()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло такое решение: (По ID поста)

```
$post27 = get_post(27);
$text = $post27->post_content; // контент поста
echo apply_filters('the_content', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Назначить эту страницу главной в настройках чтения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужна функция которую нужно написать на index.php

Comment: @Dreamer в таком случае тебе нужно научиться нормально задавать вопросы.

Comment: да, ты прав я тут недавно зарегистрировался, поправил вопрос